# normalizing table

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, normalization

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|   id   |   firstname   |   lastname   |   foods       |
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|   1    |   James       |   Bonds      |   BBQ         |
|   2    |   James       |   Bonds      |   Hamburger   |
|   3    |   James       |   Bonds      |   Pizza       |
|   4    |   David       |   Smith      |   BBQ         |
|   5    |   David       |   Smith      |   Pizza       |
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

This is my code when inserting to database:

```
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_info VALUES ('NULL', '$fname','$lname', '".$checkbox[$i]."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
 }
}
```

Or is it possible to make it like this:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|   id   |   firstname   |   lastname   |   foods       |
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|   1    |   James       |   Bonds      |   BBQ         |
|   1    |   James       |   Bonds      |   Hamburger   |
|   1    |   James       |   Bonds      |   Pizza       |
|   2    |   David       |   Smith      |   BBQ         |
|   2    |   David       |   Smith      |   Pizza       |
+--------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

The 'foods' column is a check box value so it came up redundant(if the user selected 10 check box value it will also produce 10 rows with the same first name and so on).

The problem is if I need to alter the information of the user, I have to alter it 1 by 1 and that's so wrong. And if I am going to delete the users information, the training column  values should also be deleted all at once.(I must not use implode or explode).
I'm sorry. new to php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should have three tables:

```
Person Table (person_id, firstname, lastname)

Food Table (food_id, name)

PersonFood Table (person_id, food_id)
```

When you are inserting a records, enter the person details to the person table. Have the food details stored in the food table. When a person likes a food, add a record to the PersonFood table which will contain the person_id and the food_id. This way, when a person detail changes you only need to change the record in the person table.
When retrieving results you can have a join query.

This type of normalization form is called [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Comment: I have already done 3 tables and I think I'm stuck in where to put the JOIN statement. this is the statement I going to use:                                            SELECT person.firstname, person.lastname, food.name
FROM personfood
JOIN person ON personfood.person_id = person.person_id
JOIN food ON personfood.food_id = food.food_id

Comment: I've already done this. thanks a lot. but my last problem is when I add new values, nothing happens in the display. others game me this statement: $sql = "INSERT INTO FoodFavorites (person_id, food_id) VALUES ($person_id, $food_id)"; for the 3rd table when I will add new value. but there's an error. undefined variable in $person_id and food_id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a FOOD table with items.  If a PERSON can only have one favorite, then a foreign key to FOOD is sufficient.  If there can be many favorites, then a JOIN table is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is N:N relationship.

N people exists

N types of food exists

Any person can want any food.

The **problem** with the table you've written is this:

1. Lets say you delete James Bonds. Hamburger is now deleted from the table. But Hamburgers still exist but in your table it looks like it doesn't (Understood?)
2. Lets say I select everyone who likes Pizza and Hamburger. James Bonds name will appear twice which is wrong because he's one person

.... I could go on pointing out methods with the concept you've described above.

**How to normalize it**

You should have 3 tables

```
Person (person_id, firstname, lastname)

Food (food_id, name)

PersonFood_Join (person_id, food_id)
```

where (and I hope you know foreign keys)

> PersonFood_Join(person_id) is a foreign key to Person(person_id)
>
> Food_Join(food_id) is a foreign key to Food(food_id).

As the food data is static (bunch of checkboxes) its easy to insert them and keep them permanently there.

Adding 1 row per person removes all the anomalies pointed above (note now only one copy of a person's name and one copy of food exists so no duplication)

[Here](http://psoug.org/reference/normalization.html) is an article on Normal Forms

Comment: Thank... but now if I add another information, nothing happens in the PersonFood_Join. I think it will an INSERT statement. But I don't know how to do that. thanks in advance

Comment: You have to write 2 insert statements. INSERT into Person. INSERT INTO PersonFood_Join. Use the id generated from the first in the second insert. Though this is more complex its logically better

Comment: Can you please show the code... because this codes doesn't work and `$sql4 = "INSERT INTO PersonFood_Join (food_id) (SELECT food_id FROM Food)";`(this code copy the inserted id). It is because I think that the Food table accepts multiple values at the same time which my code can't do.

Answer (score 0):

When normalizing tables you need to ask yourself: How many kinds of data am I dealing with?

In this case you have two kinds of data: A person's name, and a food item. It is possible to break it up even further by saying that a person's name consists of a first name and a last name, but for this let us just say that two kinds of data is enough.

So, we need a table for persons, foods and then one table to bring it all together. So, something like this:

```
Person
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|   id   |   firstname   |   lastname   |
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|   1    |   James       |   Bonds      |
|   2    |   David       |   Smith      |
+--------+---------------+--------------+
Food
+--------+---------------+
|   id   |   name        |
+--------+---------------+
|   1    |   BBQ         |
|   2    |   Hamburger   |
|   3    |   Pizza       |
+--------+---------------+
FoodFavorites
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|   id   |   person_id   |   food_id    |
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|   1    |   1           |   1          |
|   2    |   1           |   2          |
|   3    |   1           |   3          |
|   4    |   2           |   1          |
|   5    |   2           |   3          |
+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

And you can insert new values like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO FoodFavorites (person_id, food_id) VALUES ($person_id, $food_id)";
```

Comment: I got error on the the INSERT statement. undefined variable person_id and food_id.

Comment: I need to declare that variables with POST or something and their value must come from the id of person table and food table.